# is it correct to use "in" with "date" in this context

Tags: prepositions

I am writing this sentence

> I would like to know the maximum date **in** which I should upload my report if I want to do the presentation in October

is it correct to use **in** ?

Answer (score 8):

We normally say **on** a date, for example:

> My birthday is **on** the 29th of April

This also applies to named days, for example **on** Christmas day and **on** independence day.

Here is an [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=date%20on%20which%2C%20date%20in%20which&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdate%20on%20which%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdate%20in%20which%3B%2Cc0) that confirms that **on** is the most widely used preposition in the specific context that you mentioned (date on/in which).

Note that you should say **the latest date** rather than **the maximum date**.

You could also indicate that you want to upload the report before the latest date (rather than on the last day) by saying **the date by which**: [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20date%20by%20which%2C%20latest%20date%20on%20which%2C%20latest%20date%20by%20which&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20date%20by%20which%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clatest%20date%20on%20which%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clatest%20date%20by%20which%3B%2Cc0) shows that it occurs a lot more frequently than the other two options. You could also say **the latest/last date by which** but it is much less widely used.

> I would like to know the date **by** which I should upload my report if I want to do the presentation in October

Comment: As @StephenCalder said in his answer, "by" is also acceptable - and in my opinion better. If you say "the latest date on which...", then you're saying you'll submit it as late as possible. If you say "the latest date by which..." then you imply that you might submit it weeks earlier.

Comment: @JohnBurger: I have updated my answer.

Comment: [Better NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=last+date+on+which%2Cdate+by+which&year_start=1800).  The most natural ways of saying this are "last day on which" or "day by which".  You don't need "latest" or "last" with "by", and "last" is more common than the more formal "latest".  And it shouldn't be "I should" but "I can" with "last day on".  Because you shouldn't wait until the last day but you can.

Comment: @Brythan@ good point, although it's risky comparing a three-word ngram with a four-word Ngram. Adding "the" makes it fair and proves your point. I have updated my anwer again.

Comment: @JavaLatte You did not mention, if it is right or wrong to use **in** here. So may i know whether it is partially acceptable or not acceptable, to use **in** here ?

Comment: @A---B The NGram shows a very small number instances where **in** is used, but  most are variants of "from the date, in which" which has a completely different meaning. I think that the answer is therefore: No, you cannot use **in** in this context.

Answer (score 6):

The use of "by" for "before" in this context is also acceptable; I would like to know the [final] date by which I should submit my report etc.

Answer (score 5):

Just a brief note that might be taken note of:

The latest time or date by which something should be completed is called a [*deadline*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/deadline). This noun collocates with prepositions *at, before, by, after* —  going before it , and *for* —  following it.

Examples:

> Circled dates indicate all the deadlines, past and future.
>
> The time limit has been set, and the deadline is very close.
>
> The deadline for submitting a claim to the fund is Monday.
>
> I have enclosed an application form for you to complete and return to
>   me before the deadline marked on it.

Answer (score 3):

You should use **by** instead of **in**.

In this context, we use **by** to mean "no later than," so if you read some instructions saying:

> Upload your report **by** Monday, Sept. 19th.

that would mean you have to upload your report *no later than* Sept. 19th.

I would also suggest that you use a different word in place of *maximum*. Minimum and maximum imply that you are talking about a quantity of items that follow a normal counting sequence (0,1,2,3...), which is not really the case when we are talking about dates. Instead you could use the word **latest** or possibly **final**.

So here is how I would change this sentence:

> I would like to know the **latest** date **by** which I should upload my report if I want to do the presentation in October.

Hope this helps!